# Craft 2 Looping Through Assets Limit 100

Tags: assets, image, craft2, loop

In Craft 2, I am looping through Image Assets, but the loop stops after 100 images.
I currently have around 140 images, but only the first 100 appear.
Is this a built in limit in Craft 2?

Thanks

```
 {% for image in craft.assets.kind('image').folderId('72').order('filename') %}

 {{ image.title }}

 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element queries in Craft 2.x has a default limit of 100 (from Craft 3 and onwards, there is no default limit).

To change the default limit in Craft 2, you can pass the desired limit via the `.limit()` param. To remove the limit entirely, you can pass `null`:

```
{% for image in craft.assets.kind('image').folderId('72').order('filename').limit(null) %}
...
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was wondering if it was a default, as I hadn't run up against the limit before.